# Key Permutation in DES System using Java

Tags: java, permutation, des

Assume I have a (8*8) bit block (64-bit block).. and I need to permute it according to a given Permutation table . The Permutation table (8*7) the location of each bit in the 64 bit block to be permuted.

```
 Example:
(64=bits)        Permutation Tbale (8*7)
0 0 1 0 ..       57 49 41 ...
0 1 1 0 ..  AND  1  58 50 ..
1 0 0 1 ..       10 2 59 ...
. .
```

So from the Permutation Table.. the number 57 identifies that the bit 57 from the 64-bit block is be placed as the first bit (Place of 57 in permutation Table) of the new (8*7) Array. Is there some way using the number 57 to identify the exact row and coloumn of the 57th bit ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the indices all start at 0, `57 / 8 = 7`, so row with index 7 (8th row). `57 % 8 = 1`, so column with index 1 (2nd column).

Comment: I tried that approach before.. but it doesn't always work.. lets take for example the bit 63 which is placed at row 7 (8th row) and column 6 (7th column) but 63/8 = 7 (correct) and 63 % 8 = 7 (incorrect)

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: Sizes of the bit block and Permutation table are different

Comment: Assuming the indices start at 0, the bit 63 is the last bit, so its coordinates are [7, 7]. If the bit 63 is at [7, 6], then it simply means that indices start at 1 and not 0. So just remove 1 to the index before dividing: `(63 - 1) / 8 = 7`; `(63 - 1) % 8 = 6`.